# Asterisks in sales orders

Tags: admin, sales-order

I'm new to Magento and I'm on my learning curve. Recently I've installed on my test VM the latest and greatest ver. 2.4.2-p1.
I did a few test orders and I can't find a reason why, when being logged in as admin with theoretically full permissions, sales orders are sanitized with asterisks:
[image: sanitized addresses]

If I try to edit them I'm given information:

> Access Denied You don't have permision to view

I've been trying to find information on different sorts of blogs, forums and so on, nothing. I can't find any related settings except User roles, which in case of admin, are set to "All". I did create different users (admins and other), and nothing. Can you point me at the right direction?

Comment: is this a vanilla installation?

Comment: @DianaBotean it wasn't. I realized that I have installed Magesuite 7.0.0. At first I disabled all Elasticsuite's modules and nothing changed. After disabling Magesuite's modules all came back to normal. I don't know which exactly (Magesuite) module is responsible for this error.
To confirm that I installed second instance of Magento and it was exactly the same...

Comment: not sure i folllow, so you are saying you are having these issues on the second instance where you don't have any 3rd party modules, you still have the problem?

Comment: Sorry, wasn't too specific. I'd installed second instance Magento along with Magesuite only. Case is solved now. Please see my answer...

Comment: no problem, glad you sorted this out :) cheers!

Answer (score 2):

I've just got clarification on Magesuite GitHub:

> It's default GDPR related protection. There are two methods of
> disabling it:
>
> Create a new admin role that has "Hide customer data" permission
> unchecked Disable/remove MageSuite_Gdpr module

So, case closed...